# C# plugin 3.2.1/3.3 & SonarQube 4.0

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I know this is basic question, but still want to ask as my predecessor has informed that it has been done but SonarQube is saying something else

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

This links shows that C# plug-in 3.2.1/3.3 is compatible with SonarQube 4.2 - 5.1.

Does it means that it can not be used for SonarQube 4.0 version?
If it can be used then what features will not be available?

Problem here is that we can not upgrade SonarQube version to 4.2 but we want to use either of these C# Plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube C# Plugin version 4.x are now compatible with the new MSBuild SonarQube Runner, which makes analyzing .NET project straightforward.

You really want to directly go to that version of the plugin, and not install any of the outdated C# 3.x versions.

I highly encourage you to push forward the upgrade of your SonarQube server as a mandatory step towards adding the analysis of C# projects.

The Long-Term-Support version of SonarQube is now 4.5.x: This corresponds to the "oldest" version that SonarSource, the company behind SonarQube - is providing support for.

Now, if you really wish to proceed with SonarQube 4.0, you'll be on your own.